# Ubuntu won't boot on PowerMac G5 without the CD

Tags: unix, powerpc, g5, power-mac

I have managed to install Ubuntu onto my PowerMac G5 by changing the graphics card, but it will not start up again unless I use the CD.

Any suggestion on how to make Ubuntu boot without the CD?

Comment: You need to make a persistent installation, not just a "Live" install.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ